# Проблема с передачей значений между окнами JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, controller

в Java новичок. Задача - 
1) в главном окне вызывается модальное с заданным fxml.
2) в модальном в поле Label вводится значение
3) При закрытии модального окна введенное в label значение отображается в Label главного окна
4) У каждого окна свой контроллер и fxml

**Проблема:**
при передаче значения внутри одного контроллера все работает, при передаче из модального окна ошибка:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -javaagent:/home/lezvie/intelijIDEA/idea/ideaIU-2018.3/idea-IU-183.4284.148/lib/idea_rt.jar=35797:/home/lezvie/intelijIDEA/idea/ideaIU-2018.3/idea-IU-183.4284.148/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/lezvie/IdeaProjects/timer/out/production/timer sample.Main
Gtk-Message: 21:53:36.540: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.SecondWindowController.setValue(SecondWindowController.java:45)
    at sample.SecondWindowController.lambda$initialize$0(SecondWindowController.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Я уже отчаялся(( подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема.
Привожу весь код

код:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/gui.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Таймер");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 235, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
package sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller {

    protected Stage secondWindow;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Label LabelValue;

    @FXML
    private Button addTimer;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        addTimer.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                callPanel();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        });
    }

    protected void setTextLabel(String text){
        LabelValue.setText(text);
    }

    private void callPanel() throws IOException{
        Parent root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/secondWindow.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        secondWindow = stage;
        secondWindow.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        secondWindow.setScene(new Scene(root, 350, 200));
        secondWindow.show();
    }
}
```

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class SecondWindowController extends Controller{

    //private String labelValue;

    @FXML
    private Button ok;

    @FXML
    private TextField date;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        ok.setOnAction(event -> {
            getDateValue();
           try {
            setValue();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            closeWindow();
        });
    }

    protected String getDateValue() {
        return date.getText();
    }

    private void setValue() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("gui.fxml"));
        Controller getController = loader.getController();
        String labelValue = getDateValue();
        getController.setTextLabel(labelValue);
    }

    private void closeWindow() {
        super.secondWindow = (Stage) ok.getScene().getWindow();
        secondWindow.close();
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #412227;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="addTimer" layoutX="53.0" layoutY="228.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Добавить таймер" />
      <ScrollPane prefHeight="182.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <content>
            <Label fx:id="LabelValue" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="178.0" style="-fx-background-color: gray;" />
         </content></ScrollPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="124.0" prefWidth="375.0" style="-fx-background-color: #452d35;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.SecondWindowController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="date" layoutX="56.0" layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="260.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="Label" />
      <Button fx:id="ok" layoutX="177.0" layoutY="76.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="ok" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать два варианта.

1. Первый несколько топорный, но в целом рабочий вариант
   в методе `callPanel()` потребуется выделить `FXMLoader` в отдельную переменную и после вызова `load()` из нее можно забрать `secondController = fxmloader.getController` (синтаксис по памяти) вашего второго окна. А далее перед вызовом show() выполнить `secondController.setMainController(this)`. Теперь у второго контроллера появится связь с основным и можно дергать его методы.

   2. Второй способ использует немного магии.
      Что бы связать несвязанные классы в приложении можно использовать паттерн Publisher/Subscruber. 
      Тут нужно будет почитать документацию. Одна из его реализация называется `EventBus`, вроде есть еще вторая популярная, но название не вспомнил. Суть в том, что оба контроллера в своих методах инициализации подписываются на события. Когда второй контроллер отправит событие, то eventBus вызовет у первого метод, который отвечает за обработку этого события.

Comment: Большое спасибо, пока пробую реализовать первый вариант. Подскажите пожалуйста что такое setMainController - это внутренний метод какой-то или его описать где-то надо? Сейчас ошибка Cannot resolve method 'setMainController(sample.Controller)' кратко код выглядит так:

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/secondWindow.fxml"));
        SecondWindowController secondController = loader.getController();
secondController.setMainController(this); ???

Comment: Это сеттер, устанавливающий во втором контроллере в поле ссылку на основной контроллер, да его надо создать.